# Rails 3 with wicked_pdf - generating a pdf and displaying it in the browser works, but only creating a file doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

I can create a PDF and view it in the browser. I can even make a file while this is happening.

here in the render call I'm using

```
render :template  => 'admin/idreport.pdf.erb',
       :pdf => "ID.pdf",
       :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('../Documents', "ID.pdf")
```

the problem comes when I try to add

```
       :save_only    => true
```

once I do this, I get this error

Template is missing

Missing template admin/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/rails2/rails/foodshelf/app/views"

It looks like it wants a different admin/index, but without the save_only there is no error.

Any help would be appreciated.. This was so much easier in Rails 2 :>

Not sure if it's needed, but here is idreport.pdf.erb

```
<h3 style="text-align:center">Oxford Ecumenical Food Shelf ID Report</h3>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
<table>
   <tr><td>   </td></tr>
   <%= render :partial=>"id_report.erb", :collection => @id %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify :save_only, the results of the render isn't sent to the client, so rails attempts to find a template matching your action's name. Perhaps you should redirect to another page after saving the pdf? or send it to the client?